# Заполнение массива данными не происходит с первого раза

Tags: java, android, arraylist, glide

Всем привет. Делаю загрузку файлов на сервер с предварительным уменьшением размера и качества изображения.

Возникла проблема. При клике на кнопку срабатывает код, указанный ниже. Внутри кода **Glide** в массив добавляются данные и с этим всё нормально. Но за пределами **Glide** именно при первом клике массив оказывается пустым. Если же кликнут во второй раз, то массив уже не пуст и всё отрабатывает как надо.

Прошу подсказать как переделать код так, чтобы после первого же клика массив `arrayFilesToUpload` был заполнен данными?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    private List<MultipartBody.Part> arrayFilesToUpload;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
        {
        arrayFilesToUpload = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imagesAll.size(); i++)
            {
            final int count = i;
            Glide.with(getApplication()).load(imagesAll.get(i).path).asBitmap().override(x, y).fitCenter().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()
                {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation)
                    {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image/image_name_" + count + ".jpg");
                    FileOutputStream out;
                    try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, out);
                        out.close();
                        }
                    catch (IOException e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), mFile);

                    arrayFilesToUpload.add(fileToUpload);

                    Log.d("mLog", "Содержание массива: " + arrayFilesToUpload); // выводит содержание массива, даже при первом клике массив заполнен
                    }
                });
            }

        Log.d("mLog", "Элементов в массиве: " + arrayFilesToUpload.size()); // при первом клике выводит 0

        ...

        Retrofit...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Старайтесь избегать лишних приветствий и речевых оборотов в тексте. Они не несут пользы, а лишь отнимают время на прочтение.

Comment: Код java выполняется не построчно, а по логике. Glide уходит в параллельный поток и код после него на самом деле выполняется сразу, а не после загрузки данных с сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glide обрабатывает изображения асинхронно (дабы не грузить UI-thread), а результат обработки приходит в коллбэк `onResourceReady(...)`.

В Вашем коде, Вы, грубо говоря, запускаете обработку изображений с помощью Glide и далее, сразу же после этого запуска Вы выводите в лог информацию о `arrayFilesToUpload`, но так как изображения еще не обработаны, то Вы и получаете нулевой размер.

Между первым и вторым кликом проходит время, и, к моменту второго клика, Glide успевает обработать изображения и размер `arrayFilesToUpload` уже не нулевой.

> Прошу подсказать как переделать код так, чтобы после первого же клика массив `arrayFilesToUpload` был заполнен данными?

Тут два варианта:

1. Производить действия с `arrayFilesToUpload` в коллбэке `onResourceReady(...)`, когда изображения будут обработаны.
2. Запускать обработку изображений синхронно, но при этом Вам нужно будет самому реализовывать логику выполнения операций в стороннем потоке, так как обработка изображений – операция относительно долгая и ее не стоит выполнять в UI-thread.

---

**UPD**:

Можно объявить интерфейс:

```
public interface OnImagesReadyListener {
    void onImagesReady(List<String> results);
}
```

И далее воспользоваться им:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> imagesPathsList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Логика по заполнению imagesPathsList

        processImages(imagesPathsList, new OnImagesReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImagesReady(List<String> results) {
                // Этот метод будет вызван когда все изображения будут обработаны
            }
        });

    }

    private void processImages(List<String> imagesPathsList, OnImagesReadyListener onImagesReadyListener) {
        final List<String> resultsImagesList = new ArrayList<>(imagesPathsList.size());

        // Далее идет обработка изображений с помощью Glide.
        // В конце коллбэка onResourceReady(...) дописываете:
        if (resultsImagesList.size() == imagesPathsList.size()) {
            onImagesReadyListener.onImagesReady(resultsImagesList);
        }
    }
}
```

PS. `String` замените на необходимый тип данных.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение. Могли вы подсказать логику первого варианта или возможно пример есть? Потому как мне в голову приходит только вариант, чтобы в onResourceReady вставить Retrofit со отправкой файла без использования массивов. Но это тот вариант, от которого я как раз сейчас пытаюсь уйти. Т.к. ранее у меня в цикле была и обработка изображения, и сразу же его отправка. Это мне показалось не совсем логично. Теперь пытаюсь создать массив из обработанных изображений и одним разом этот массив отправить на сервер.

Comment: @Gamlet, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: Внедрил ваш пример. К сожалению, ситуация один в один как у меня. Если же я конечно правильно понял, что `resultsImagesList` вашего примера соответствует `arrayFilesToUpload` моего примера.

Comment: Прошу тысячу извинений. Последние строки кода не туда воткнул. ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ )) Спасибо большое )) Это получается обработку ретрофитом и отправку теперь нужно разместить тут: `processImages(imagesPathsList, new OnImagesReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImagesReady(List<String> results) {
                // Этот метод будет вызван когда все изображения будут обработаны
            }
        });`

Comment: @Gamlet, Да, можно там.